# Удаление шумовых данных с изображения

Tags: изображения, opencv

Для подсчета площади бревен мне нужно отделить их торцы от фона. Для этого я перевел входное RGB изображение в HSV, и выделил по H(hue) и S(saturation), V(value) я не трогаю, т.к. он зависим от условий съемки. С помощью этих манипуляций получен результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из изображения, остались некоторые шумы: куски коры, фрагменты земли. В связи с этим вопрос: какие методы (кроме морфологических операций, они сработали не очень хорошо) можно применить для удаления лишних пикселей с изображения?

Comment: Уточните плиз, для тех, кто не знаком со спецификой деревообработки, какие из пикселей на приведенном изображении лишние - все что не попадает в овалы бревен снаружи или что-то еще?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, из изображения планируется получить только торцы-спилы, все остальное принимается за шумы.